# android webViewClient onReceivedError() always getting called even when there is no error

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I am loading a url in a `WebView`, but the `WebViewClient` method `OnReceivedError()` always gets called even when the page is loaded successfully. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: `onReceivedError` provides you with an `errorCode` - What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have tried monitoring `onReceivedError()` method in WebViewClient

If the page loads fine in the webview, the reason for the onReceivedError() being called is because of the warnings in the HTML/JS script, which you can just ignore, or fix by monitoring the error.

Comment: @Rawkode: The error description says that the connection to the server wqas not successful.

Comment: Then how do I know if I have to ignore the error or is this some serious error, because evry time it says 'connectio to server was not successful'.